# How to declare at the beginning of the notebook that a variable belongs to a set?

Tags: formatting, assumptions

In the notebook I am working on I have certain symbolic variables (e.g., c and r) which I would like to declare since the very first few lines to be non negative real numbers. Correct me if I am wrong but I believe that this avoids some errors and bugs (for instance I see that mathematica does not make some simplification of the symbolic expressions).

Also related I would like to ask: if a variable is not declared (as I want to do) what does mathematica presumes it belongs to? Complex number?

Comment: 1) This probably won't really work as you expect. There is no such thing as a global declaration in MMA. The closest you can get is to add your assumptions to `$Assumptions`. But beware: only those functions that work with assumptions will be influenced by this! `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` would work though. From a style and maintainability standpoint, I would recommend that you add those assumptions explicitly at your "point of use" though, so the behavior of your code does not depend on remote portions you may later forget about.

Comment: 2) Yes, MMA will assume that everything is a complex number if not told otherwise.